# Why is parseInt in java unable to identify integers in my input string?

Tags: java, numberformatexception

After inputting a string and separating it into different parts, I have used parseInt to separate integers from an input string. But while running the program, a NumberFormatException generated on the string `"     4"`, which clearly has the integer `'4'` in it. `input` is a file reading scanner type variable already declared in the program prior to this operation.

```java
String line = input.nextLine();
String[] part = line.split(",  ");

int tempParticleNumber;

tempParticleNumber = Integer.parseInt(part[0]);
```

The terminal output is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "      4"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:638)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
```

Expected process is that the input string `"    4"` is converted to an integer `4`, but this doesn't happen.

Comment: there is space in front of 4, like this " 4", so trim the string and then convert it `Integer.parseInt(part[0].trim())`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply `trim()` the whitespaces:

```
tempParticleNumber = Integer.parseInt(part[0].trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't taken into account the space that is coming with part[0], your part[0] is not '4', its ' 4' which is not an integer.

Try doing this :

```
line = line.substring(1);
String[] part = line.split(",  ");
int tempParticleNumber;
tempParticleNumber = Integer.parseInt(part[0]);
```

This will make the string get rid of the initial space.

Comment: You're right about the cause of the error, but for the solution you can consider using `line = line.Trim();` or `tempParticlaNumber = Integer.parseInt(part[0].Trim())`. `Trim()` removes all leading and trailing spaces or line-breaks etc. from a string.